# How do i need define the user? ReferenceError: user is not defined Steam user

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, steam, steam-web-api

when im starting my script, this error shows up:

```html
/var/www/html/bot/driver.js:309
    if(users[user.steamid])
             ^

ReferenceError: user is not defined
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/bot/driver.js:309:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Namespace.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Namespace.emit (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:213:10)
    at /var/www/html/bot/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:181:14
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Can someone explain this to me? How do i need to define the steam user?
The part in the script where it crashes looks so:

```html
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var index = -1;
    if(users[user.steamid])
    index = users[user.steamid]['socket'].indexOf(socket.id);
    if (index > -1) {
        users[user.steamid]['socket'].splice(index, 1);
    }
    if(users[user.steamid]) { if(Object.keys(users[user.steamid]['socket']).length == 0) delete users[user.steamid]; }
  });
```

Before in the console, it asks me for the Steam Guard Code, but then it immediately crashes to that error.

Comment: Is you 'user' variable defined? like var user = {steamid: 'string'} somewhere where this function can access this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually tell the system what `user` is, it has no idea what it is because you haven't defined it anywhere and it doesn't have any reference or source from where it originated.

If you do something like:

```
const user = 'something';
```

It will at least be defined, but that's just about as useless as not defining it because you're obviously missing some logic from a library or something along those lines because `user` should be defined.